# Viewstate : NullReference exception ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Well,I got a NullReference exception when I tried to execute out the code.
I am just trying to save the current student instance in Viewstate["contents"].And the next time the page is being loaded it will show the previous instance members in the para tag.

//Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public student student1 = new student();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) 
        {
            para1.InnerText = "Last entered values were" + ((student)ViewState["contents"]).fname.ToString() + ((student)ViewState["contents"]).lname.ToString();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class student 
    {
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        student1.fname = TextBox1.Text;
        student1.lname = TextBox2.Text;
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["contents"] = student1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public student student1 = new student();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [Serializable]
        public class student
        {
            public string fname { get; set; }
            public string lname { get; set; }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            student1.fname = TextBox1.Text;
            student1.lname = TextBox2.Text;

            ViewState["contents"] = student1;
        }

        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                TextBox3.Text = "Last entered values were" + ((student)ViewState["contents"]).fname.ToString() + ((student)ViewState["contents"]).lname.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override the prerender.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreRender(e);
   ViewState["contents"] = student1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value in the `PreRender` event which called after the `Load` event. So, try setting the value before `Load` event.

```
Content page PreInit event.
Master page controls Init event.
Content controls Init event.
Master page Init event.
Content page Init event.
Content page Load event.
Master page Load event.
Master page controls Load event.
Content page controls Load event.
Content page PreRender event.
Master page PreRender event.
Master page controls PreRender event.
Content page controls PreRender event.
Master page controls Unload event.
Content page controls Unload event.
Master page Unload event.
Content page Unload event.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

you need to check whether Viewstate is null or not before going to proceed

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ViewState["contents"] = student1;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    student1.fname = TextBox1.Text;
    student1.lname = TextBox2.Text;
    ViewState["contents"] = student1;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack) 
        {
            if (ViewState["contents"] != null)
            {
                  para1.InnerText = "Last entered values were" + ((student)ViewState["contents"]).fname.ToString() + ((student)ViewState["contents"]).lname.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: well this thing was for the current page.I want current student instance to be saved in viewstate.And the next time when the page will be loaded I want my viewstate contents to be showed in the para tag.

Comment: @Ajay yes for that you need to store values into viewstate in ButtonClickevent

Comment: i tried that but the current student instance is getting destroyed everytime.So,it's giving null reference exception.Is there any way I can get these values stored in my viewstate?

Comment: @Ajay remove ViewState["contents"] = student1; this line from Page _prerender